# Selenium general authentification

Tags: c#, selenium

I wanna log in into my Proxy Server with Selenium. But I need a Username and a Password. I´m using Selenium Chrome Driver.

This is just for testing. I already tried to send general keys but I think there´s one other better method possible.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

I except that we will find a solution which is already integrated into Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the credentials in the URL itself by https://email:Password@URL. Let me know what is the result.